# ¿Cómo hago para abrir el explorador de archivos en C#?

Tags: c#

```
    private MenuStrip BarraDeMenus;
    private ToolStripMenuItem menuArchivo;
    private ToolStripMenuItem ArchivoAbrir;

menuArchivo = new ToolStripMenuItem();
menuArchivo.Name = "menuArchivo";
menuArchivo.Text = "&Archivo";
BarraDeMenus.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { menuArchivo });

ArchivoAbrir = new ToolStripMenuItem();
ArchivoAbrir.Name = "ArchivoAbrir";
ArchivoAbrir.Text = "&Abrir";
ArchivoAbrir.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control | Keys.A;
ArchivoAbrir.ShowShortcutKeys = true;
menuArchivo.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { ArchivoAbrir });
```

Estoy trabajando con menú no sé cómo abrir el explorador de archivos con botones pero con menú no he podido no sé si alguien me puede brindar su ayuda algún ejemplo.

Answer (score 3):

Te servirá la clase [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) ahí podrás crear tus opciones/restricciones (decidir qué extensiones de archivos puede leer tu programa, directorio raíz, etc), y te permite decidir qué hacer cuando has elegido un archivo.

Necesitas crear un método que responda al evento Click del objeto AbrirArchivo. Debajo de lo que publicaste agregas el método a ArchivoAbrir.

```
ArchivoAbrir.Click += ArchivoAbrir_Click;
```

Luego creas el método que estás usando:

```
void ArchivoAbrir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Y dentro de éste método usas el OpenFileDialog. Te muestro copia del código de ejemplo que está en el link que te pasé:

```
Stream myStream = null;

OpenFileDialog dialogoBuscarArchivo = new OpenFileDialog();

//Se crean las opciones que comentaba
dialogoBuscarArchivo.InitialDirectory = "c:\\" ;
dialogoBuscarArchivo.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
dialogoBuscarArchivo.FilterIndex = 2 ;
dialogoBuscarArchivo.RestoreDirectory = true ;

//el ShowDialog() muestra el explorador de archivos para que elijas tu archivo. 
//Cuando le das click a "Aceptar" se devuelve DialogResult.OK 
//y si das click a "Cancelar" se devuelve una DialogResult.Cancel
if(dialogoBuscarArchivo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        //Si fue un OK, entonces suponemos que hay un archivo. Intentamos abrirlo
        if ((myStream = dialogoBuscarArchivo.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            using (myStream)
            {
                // Aquí utilizas el archivo que has abierto
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: No se pudo leer el achivo del disco. Error original: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: el problema es que no se como aplicarlo cuando de click a abrir en el menu

Comment: Edité mi respuesta para incluir código de ejemplo

Comment: Gracias de verdad muchas gracias

Comment: Que tal Freddy, existirá algo similar, pero en vez de que trabaje con archivos sea con carpetas?

Comment: Creo que es mejor que hagas una nueva pregunta donde puedas explicarnos qué harás con esa(s) carpeta(s). Pero te adelanto que lo más probable es que necesites la clase  FolderBrowserDialog. Con eso consigues un string con la ruta de la carpeta, en vez de un objeto con todos los archivos adentro.